# error while getting data from file to array

Tags: java

I'm trying to get saved data in a text file to an array to use it in my code and then search this array for a string submitted from the user from the GUI , but for some reason I print out the data in the array it is all null. here's the code !!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IO {

    File f = new File("DB.txt");
    PrintWriter write;
    Scanner input;
    String[][] data;
    String nameToSearch;

    // search constructor
    public IO(String name) {
        super();
        nameToSearch = name;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found please restart the program");
        }
        data = new String[linesCounter()][2];
        int i = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            data[i][0] = input.nextLine();
            data[i][1] = input.nextLine();
            i++;
        }
    }

    public IO(String name, String number) {
        try {
            write = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        write.println(name);
        write.println(number);
        write.close();
    }

    int linesCounter() {
        try {
            input = new Scanner(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found please restart the program");
        }
        int counter = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            input.nextLine();
            counter++;
        }
        return counter / 2;
    }

    int contactFinder() {
        int i = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            if (data[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(nameToSearch))
                return i;
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    String nameGetter() {
        return data[contactFinder()][0];
    }

    String numGetter() {
        return data[contactFinder()][1];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you read all the lines in from the file to count how many lines there are, and then when you go to read the data, you're starting from where you left off, which would be the end of the file.

It's also worth noting that you can use [commons-io FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29) to easily read all the lines from a file.

For example:

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(f);
String[][] data = new String[lines.length][2];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    data[i][i % 2] = lines.get(i);
}
```

If you also don't want to use a (very useful) third party library, you could load up the data pretty simply with:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(input.nextLine());
}
input.close();
```

Then go into the array population.

Comment: I thought that might be it but I could't reset the scanner back to start of the file, any idea how to do that ?

Comment: You could just create a new one, but there's no sense in reading the whole file twice. Just load it into a List<String> the first time around, preferably using a common utility like I added to my answer, and then go from there. Remember that a Scanner is basically a stream and needs to be [closed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()).

Comment: I'm not familiar lists yet so I'm using a normal array instead

Comment: Lists are easier than arrays, actually. I added an example of loading up your data to my answer. I think that'll give you the array you're looking for in much less code.

Comment: is FileUtils a standard java class ?? because it cannot be resolved on Java !!

Comment: It's from commons-io, linked earlier in my answer.

Comment: If you're on JDK 7, the new [java.nio.file.Files class has a similar method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Comment: That's fine. Use commons-io, or check the new update to my answer.

Comment: now it gives me another exception in the GUI class !!!!!! that didn't happen before !!

Comment: Probably because you weren't getting past this before, and now you've found a new bug.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use [**RandomAccessFile**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). This has methods such as `readLine()` to read the line and `seek(long pos)` to set the file read pointer. You may use `seek(0L)` to restart the reading of the file.

Comment: what does the String mode means ??

Comment: @user1712638 Where do you see String mode?